# listagg in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have this sql query in Oracle:

```
SELECT listagg(A.name, ",") within group (ORDER BY A.id) as A,
listagg(B.name, ",") within group (ORDER BY B.id) as B
FROM some_table
join A on A.id = some_table.id
join B.name = some_table.name
where some_table.status in (1,2,3)
group by some_table.id
```

My problem is I get duplicated results from the listagg which I do not want.
How can I fix that?
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Since 19c, LISTAGG aggregate function now supports duplicate elimination by using the new DISTINCT keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not support `distinct` for `listagg()` prior to Oracle 19.

In your case, though, the problem is presumably caused by a Cartesian product as a result of the `join`s.  That suggests that correlated subqueries are a better approach:

```
select t.*,
       (select listagg(a.name, ',') within group (order by a.id)
        from A a
        where a.id = t.id 
       ) as a,
       (select listagg(b.name, ',') within group (order by b.id)
        from B b
        where b.id = t.id 
       ) as b
from some_table t
where t.status in (1, 2, 3)
group by t.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Listagg function doesn't support distinct option. You should use subquery for select unique values.